# Creating a tuple in post-process execute command of OPL

Tags: cplex, opl

I have a worker assignment problem where jobs have three components
(sub-skills) to identify them:

{job} Jobs = { < c1, c2, c3 > | c1 in Cat1, c2 in Cat2, c3 in Cat3 };

From the pool of workers I now create tuples of possibilities
for assigning a worker to a job if they match the criteria:

{possibleTuple} = Possibles = { < n, c1, c2, c3 > | < c1,c2,c3> in Jobs, n in Workers };

A binary array onTeam[Possibles] indicates if worker n is assigned to the team.

My model runs fine and I am getting sensible results.  However, I am
unable to print these out nicely in the post-processing "execute"
command.  I would like to output the team of workers for each job with
something like:

```
for (var j in Jobs)
{
   for (var n in Workers)
   {
     if onTeam[<n,c1,c2,c3>] == 1, output n
   }
}
```

It is this inner logic that I am having difficulty with.  I am not able
to recreate the tuple  in order to index the onTeam set.

Can anybody help, please?

Many thanks,
Patrick Healy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

let me give you a small example:

```
{string} Cat1={"A","B"};
{string} Cat2={"C","D"};
{string} Cat3={"E","F"};

tuple job
{
string j1;
string j2;
string j3;
}

{job} Jobs = { < c1, c2, c3 > | c1 in Cat1, c2 in Cat2, c3 in Cat3 };

{string} Workers={"Albert","Bob","Charles"};

tuple possibleTuple
{
string n;

string j1;
string j2;
string j3;
}

{possibleTuple} Possibles = { < n, c1, c2, c3 > | < c1,c2,c3> in Jobs, n in Workers };

dvar boolean onTeam[Possibles];

subject to
{
onTeam[<"Albert","A","C","E">]==1;
onTeam[<"Bob","A","C","E">]==1;
onTeam[<"Charles","A","C","F">]==1;
}

{string} workersPerJob[j in Jobs]=
{w | w in Workers : onTeam[<w,j.j1,j.j2,j.j3>]==1};

execute
{
for(var j in Jobs) if ( workersPerJob[j].size!=0)
{
writeln("for job ",j," workers : ", workersPerJob[j]);
}
}
```

which gives

```
for job  <"A" "C" "E"> workers :  {"Albert" "Bob"}
for job  <"A" "C" "F"> workers :  {"Charles"}
```